# Can I use shorthand margin syntax to change just left and right values?

Tags: html, css

Can I use the shorthand margin syntax if I want to add `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` while leaving the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` alone?

The basic idea:

```
.center {
    margin: dont-specify auto;
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit:** In short, the answer is that there is no such keyword. For clarity, by 'dont-specify', I did not mean 'remove-specification', 'roll-back-specification' or 'specify-with-lower-specificity'. I meant, 'this rule should not specify a new value'. I take responsibility for being unclear. It is indeed very easy to interpret 'dont-specify' a multitude of different ways! Thanks for everyone's answers!

Comment: short answer: nope not with the shortcode. Either the whole `margin: top right bottom right or margin-{direction}: {value}`

Comment: That's what I thought. In my search, I even learned about "unset", which I had never heard of before. Seems like an oversight in CSS, but I'll live.

Comment: u can just use auto for the other values if u like. The shortform that you can use is `margin: {whatever} auto` - this will set `{whatever}` for `bottom` and `auto` for `left` aswell.

Comment: If the element being styled has margin-top: 20px and margin-bottom: 10px at the moment, won't using "auto", overwrite that?

Comment: it will in this case. I refered to when u have no values set already.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still looking for an answer, you can use `margin-inline` property:

```
.center {
    margin-inline: auto;
}
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline.

Answer (score 2):

Not in shorthand no.  Possible values are:

```
margin:10px; // top/right/bottom/left
margin:10px 10px; // top/bottom left/right
margin:10px 10px 10px; // top right/left bottom
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px; // top right bottom left
```

Comment: This is now possible with `margin-inline`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71885096/1852005

Answer (score 0):

```
.center {margin:0 auto;}
```

This is assuming you know your top and bottom margins are the same value. the first value is your top and bottom. the second is your right and left.

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE (2022)

Nowadays and since a while you can now use [margin-inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline), like this:
`margin-inline: auto`

> The margin-inline CSS shorthand property is a shorthand property that
> defines both the logical inline start and end margins of an element,
> which maps to physical margins depending on the element's writing
> mode, directionality, and text orientation.

#### OLD answer

**OP comment**

> If the element being styled has margin-top: 20px and margin-bottom:
> 10px at the moment, won't using "auto", overwrite that?

**A:** yes you can, It all depends on your specificity.

###Snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
main {
  border: solid green
}
div,
span,
article,
section {
  display: block; /* needed for span */
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: dashed red 1px
}
/* override margin-left/right */
[class*="class-"] {
  margin: auto; /* shorthand for top right bottom left - or - top/bottom right/left */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <span class="class-1"></span>
  <div class="class-2"></div>
  <article class="class-3"></article>
  <section class="class-4"></section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

theoraticly , there will be options somedays :

> https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#defaulting (about inherit, unset, initial & revert)

but seems not implemented anywhere yet :( , so you still need to write :

```
margin-left : auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

---

below test with `revert`, feel free to copy and swap `revert` with the 3 other values.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: orange
}
p {
  width: 80%;
  margin: revert auto;
  border: solid;
  background: turquoise
}
div:first-child p:first-child {
  margin: auto;
  background: tomato;
}
div + div p:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>margin:0;</p>
  <p>margin test</p>
  <p>margin test</p>
  <p>margin test</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>margin test</p>
  <p>margin test</p>
  <p>margin test</p>
  <p>margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've think this is possible at least I did in my answer due to specificity

Comment: I'm referring to my snippet not your pen using `revert` :)

Comment: @dippas added a snippet too, so you have live the difference. some day revert should come avalaible :)

Comment: I think 'revert' is actually incorrect for my purpose. Revert potentially changes the value of margin-top and margin-bottom by rolling back the cascade. What I was looking for is a keyword that would in no way influence the margin-top or margin-bottom values set by browser, user or author.

Comment: @Mike i said revert from infos we had at this time in the question. Anyhow, actually, the only option is to write rules for right and left, short hands option are not avalaible yet :)

Comment: In any case, I had never heard of 'revert', so I appreciate you bringing it to my attention.